# Angular 2 Promise always returns null ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

A few days ago, I stared to learn ASP.NET Core and Angular 2. So far, so good, except today.
A little introduction to my problem.

I have a really simple Web Api controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{       
    private readonly ForumSystemDbContext dbContext;

    public HomeController(ForumSystemDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var posts = this.dbContext.Posts
            .Include(x => x.PostTag)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Tag)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Title = x.Title,
                Content = x.Content,
                Tags = x.PostTag.Select
                (
                    y => new
                    {
                        name = y.Tag.Name
                    }
                )
            });

        return this.Json(posts);
    }
}
```

An angular service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

export class Post {
    Content: string;
    Title: string;
    Tags: Tag[];
}

export class Tag {
    Name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
    private postsUrl = 'http://localhost:54692/api/home';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getPosts(): Promise<Post[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.postsUrl)
                        .toPromise()
                        .then(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Promise.reject(errMsg);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();

        return body.data || {};
    }
}
```

And finally home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeService } from '../services/home.service';

export class Post {
    Content: string;
    Title: string;
    Tags: Tag[];
}

export class Tag {
    Name: string;
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: Post[] = [];

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private homeService: HomeService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.homeService.getPosts()
            .then(posts => this.posts = posts);
    }
}
```

The problem is that posts variable is always an empty array. When i log

```
this.homeService.getPosts()
```

it's returns

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array[0]}
```

I have read the official angular 2 documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#promises, but unfortunately it doesn't work in my case.

So, i was wondering where is my mistake?

Is it a some kind of configuration issue or something else ?

Comment: Quick question. You use body.data in extractData, but I can't see .data in your API anywhere. Am I missing something? Also, how do you log getPosts()?

Comment: you have to `import 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: @PankajParkar I did it, but the result is the same.

Comment: @BojanKogoj I just followed the Angular 2 introduction tutorial.  I log getPosts() in home.component.ts in ngOnInit().

Comment: @BojanKogoj he is converting the http response to a JSON response then using dot notation to access the JSON object members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();

  return body.data || {};
}
```

to

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  return res.json();
}
```

There is no `data` property in your response

```
[{"Title":"title1","Content":"","Tags":[]},{"Title":"title2","Content":"","Tags":[]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach for the service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
  private postsUrl = 'http://localhost:54692/api/home';
  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getPosts(){
    return this.http.get(this.postsUrl).map(
        res => res.json()
    );
  }

}
```

and consume it from the component like below.

```
getPosts(){
    this.homeService.getPosts().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.posts = data;
      },
      error => {

      },
      () => {}
    );
  }
```

Here, `this.homeService` is an instance of your service and `this.posts` is just a local variable which will get populated by your posts returned from Web API.

Home it helps.

Comment: This approach will work also, but i prefer to work with promises. Thanks anyway.